# Mssql 2012 Row Locking

Tags: database, entity-framework

i have lots of data on database, and lots of users are updating these data via async JS.
i want to prevent multiple users modify same row on db. When user 1 clicks edit row in web page i want to send a signal to server and lock this row. So other users wont be able to access edit mode on this same row. When user finishes editing row, he/she will click ok, updates will be committed and row will be unlocked. i searched google for this approach but all sql locks are for single transaction. is there any way to accomplish this? i would be glad to solve this without changing my db design. but if there are no solutions without a change, lots of work will be waiting me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something towards this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Whenever the row is saved a lock_version field is counted up. Whenever a save happens on this row it will look if the lock_version on the database is the same as the one that is held in memory. If the version is different, the row has been changed by another user. Here you can do anything:

1. reload the row from the database and add the changes, then resave
2. just throw an exception and let the user handle it

If you realy want something towards what you propose, you are gonna need to handle this with some kind of flag on the row, which you set when a user is editing the row.

1. user starts editing the row -> set the flag locked to true
2. another user tries to edit the row -> flag will prevent this
3. user ends editing the row -> set the flag locked to false

However, this will give you all kinds of problems... Try to avoid this convoluted lock handling and go with something simple like optimistic locking

Comment: what kind of problems are you thinking about? on your second suggestion

Comment: right now only one springs to mind :). concurrency issue: first user wants to open the row for edit, so he reads the row then saves it back with the lock flag set to true, meanwhile another user has read the row, when the save of the first user hasn't completed. and now you have two users that are editing the same row.
you'd probably need to wrap these steps into a transaction to prevent this kind of issues (during which the row would need to be locked for other read or write operations)